# Which card should we change (and to what card) to maximize the probability of getting two pairs?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, card-games, poker

> In a standard $52$-card deck we change **8♧** with **10♤** and **9♧** with **J♤** from another deck of cards. If we change another card, which card should we change (and to what card) to maximize the probability of getting two pairs?

Here is my answer: there are $9$ ordinary ($4$ cards), $2$ weak ($3$ cards) and $2$ strong ($5$ cards) ranks. If we change another card among the $9$ ordinary ranks with the same rank as these  cards, that is $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,Q,K$, and not the same rank, we'll then maximize the chance a bit.

Does it sound correct?

Comment: I changed the word cards to ranks when you were describing ranks.  You should explain what you mean by ordinary, weak, and strong ranks.  I also suggest providing a link to your previous question so that readers understand the context for this problem.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new here so I appriciate if you edit my questions so they'll be clearer and more understandable to others.